# Oracle sql return true if exists question

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, exists

How do I check if a particular element exists in a table -  how can I return true or false?

I have a table that has

- user_id
- user_password
- user_secretQ

Verbally, I want to do this: If a particular `user_id` exists in the `user_id` column, then return true -- otherwise return false.

Comment: Desired output STRING "YES" or "NO"
And user_id is numberic

Comment: If you want to return a string, then edit your question according to that. An string saying "YES" or "NO" is not the same as a returning true or false, which would be a boolean.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is no Boolean type in Oracle SQL. You will need to return a 1 or 0, or some such and act accordingly:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(user_id) IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END User_exists
  FROM user_id_table
 WHERE user_id = 'some_user';
```

Comment: Is it throwing an error? Does your select statement work in plain old SQL*Plus?

Comment: Or `SELECT NVL2(MAX(user_ID),'YES','NO') ...`

Answer (score 11):

In PL/SQL you can do this:

```
function user_exists (p_user_id users.user_id%type) return boolean
is
  l_count integer;
begin
  select count(*)
  into   l_count
  from   users
  where  user_id = p_user_id;

  return (l_count > 0);
end;
```

This would then be used in calling PL/SQL like this:

```
if user_exists('john') then
  dbms_output.put_Line('John exists');
end if;
```

NOTE: I used count(*) in the query in the knowledge that this will only return 1 or 0 in the case of a primary key search.  If there could be more than one row then I would add "and rownum = 1" to the query to prevent unnecessarily counting many records just to find out if any exists:

```
function user_has_messages (p_user_id users.user_id%type) return boolean
is
  l_count integer;
begin
  select count(*)
  into   l_count
  from   messages
  where  user_id = p_user_id
  AND ROWNUM = 1;

  return (l_count > 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 9):

Oracle RDBMS does not have boolean data type, you can only use boolean variables in PL/SQL.

If you simply want to return strings 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'
you can do this..

```
SELECT 'TRUE'  FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM  table WHERE user_id = 'id')
UNION
SELECT 'FALSE' FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM  table WHERE user_id = 'id')
```

I like @DCookie's query though.

Comment: TIL boolean is not part of the DDL

Answer (score 4):

`select count(*) from table where userid = :userid and rownum <= 1); -- If exists then 1 else 0`

Answer (score 3):

Or you could do this:

```
select decode(max(USER_ID), null, 'FALSE', 'TRUE') BOOL_VAL
from USER_TABLE where USER_ID = [some USER_ID here]
```

Comment: A `String` with "FALSE" or "TRUE" as content is not a `Boolean` value.