# find_by_sql and select case

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Can somebody help me why the following SQL-statement won't be stored in the variable `@var`? After this statement the variable should have the value "YES" or "NO".

**SQL**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(user_id) IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END User_exists
FROM user_id_table
WHERE user_id = 'some_user';
```

I found this statement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098800/oracle-sql-return-true-if-exists-question).

**Ruby on Rails**

```
@var = Test.find_by_sql("SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(user_id) IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END user_exists
FROM user_id_table
WHERE user_id = 'some_user'")
```

Comment: Try to use  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` instead of `find_by_sql`

Comment: I don't no why but this returns always true...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows()`.